# How to serve WSGI Application on External IP with Werkzeug

Tags: wsgi, werkzeug

I am using [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/) to create and serve `VectorTiles`, I have everything working perfectly on my computer. I was also able to access the Tiles I am generating on the Network my computer is connected to by using the IP address assigned by the router (and also using the IP Address assigned by a VPN ) instead of `127.0.0.1` as the host.

I now want to serve the Tiles on a Public IP, (the one I have purchased from my ISP ). I tried using the public IP like I was using the router assigned IP with [werkzeug](http://tilestache.org/doc/#wsgi) but I get the following error:

[image]

How can I make the Tiles accessible using the Public IP with or without `Werkzeug`?

Comment: You need to port forward from your router to your computer. You won't be able to bind on that IP address though. Bind on your local network address.